# Matrices and what they represent

Tags: matrices, terminology

I know matrices can represent transformations but they can also represent the points that are transformed by another matrix do these two types have different names and if so what are they?? thanks

Comment: Matrix is just a table to contain something, some information. It comes from a Latin word that means womb. You maybe referring to some applications of these tables to represent linear transformation, for example. But they are also used for many other purposes. Representing graphs, data, images, points, data of any sort.

Comment: Then, depending on the use, one makes up operations of the matrix that imitate operations on the data they represent. For example componentwise addition and matrix multiplication, are defined when one is using the matrix to represent a linear transformation. This is done such that, when one adds or multiply matrices, that corresponds to what happens when one adds or compose linear transformations. If one changes to other uses of a matrix, for example in an image filter, the multiplication that might be useful could be componentwise.

Comment: When the matrix is used to represent a linear transformation, one calls it *the matrix of the linear transformation in certain bases*. The bases should be part of the name because the matrix representation of the data depends on those bases.

Comment: Is the way we add and multiply matrices by definition or is there some reasoning behind it e.g. it most be done this way because...

Comment: The *usual* multiplication of matrices is done with a purpose. When  $f$ and $g$ are linear transformations, and $A$ and $B$ are their matrices. The definition of matrix multiplication is done such that the matrix of $f\circ g$ is $AB$ and the matrix of $f+g$ is $A+B$. Often in courses one sees the operation being defined ad hoc, for the sake of the exposition. For example, usually matrices and their operations are studied before linear transformations are studied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, one can define a matrix as follows: Denote by $J_m$ the set $\{1,\ldots, m\}$.  Then a matrix of dimension $m\times n$ is a function $f:J_m\times J_n\rightarrow R$, where $R$ is the set of values that the entries of the matrix take on.  It is typical for $R$ to be the real numbers, $\mathbb{R}$, or the complex number, $\mathbb{C}$.

However, as others point out, matrices can be best thought of as a way of representing linear transformations between two finite-dimensional vector spaces after bases have been selected in each.  In this sense, the multiplication of two matrices corresponds to the matrix of the composition of the two linear transformations.  Addition is defined as it is because it makes the space of matrices into a vector space itself.

Comment: So, a matrix by definition is 2D?